# Is passing a function to UseEffect valid? Can this be done to replace useCallback?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Lets say I do this

```js
// Get a hook function
const {
  useState,
  useEffect
} = React;

const Example = ({
  title
}) => {
  const [formVal, setFormVal] = useState("")
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const increment = () => setCount(count + 1)

  // now use increment as just the cb for useeffect
  useEffect(increment, [formVal])

  return ( <
    div >
    <input onChange={(e) => setFormVal(e)} placeholder="test"/>
    <
    p > {
      title
    } < /p> <
    p > You interacted {
      count
    }
    times < /p> <
    button onClick = {
      increment
    } >
    Click me <
    /button> < /
    div >
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render( <
  Example title = "Example using Hooks:" / > ,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Instead of calling `increment` inside of a `useEffect` anonymous callback, I just made the whole thing the first argument. My question is, does that remove the need to wrap the `increment` into a useCallback?

Please note this is a super contrived example, lets assume here that there are other rerenders happening at the same time, and the goal is to not have useless commits or rerenders.

Answer (score 1):

> Is passing a function to UseEffect valid?

Yes. Main purpose is to keep the function reusable. Make sure, it returns nothing / `void` or a parameter-less function `() => {...}` as clean up. Otherwise, React emits a console error.

> Can this be done to replace useCallback?

No. Following `useEffect` Hooks behave *exactly* the same:

```
const increment = () => setCount(count + 1) //  declared somewhere inside component

useEffect(increment, [formVal]) 
useEffect(() => setCount(count + 1), [formVal]) // inline variant of increment
```

A new function is created with each render cycle in both versions. `useEffect` invokes this passed-in function after render, as soon as *one item of the dependency array* (`formVal`) changes - *not* `increment`.

---

### Missing dependency in `useEffect`

There is a subtle bug: Currently, `count` references a *stale value* inside the effect. `useEffect` also needs `count` as dependency, as `increment` uses it. You can inline the `increment` effect callback and ESLint will warn you: `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'count'`. Illustration:

```js
const Example = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  const increment = () => {
    // count dependency is missing / state closure scope
    // => state will always be reset to initial count value
    // we could use funtional updater, but this is just for demonstration
    const handle = setInterval(() => setCount(count + 1), 2000);
    return () => clearInterval(handle);
  };

  React.useEffect(increment, []);

  // this triggers ESLint react hooks warning (ESLint not supported on SO)
  // useEffect(() => { count; }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You interacted {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
      <p>Click the button. The interval resets counter every 2 sec. because of a stale count value</p>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-32Gmw5rBDXyMjg/73FgpukoTZdMrxuYW7tj8adbN8z4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-bjQ42ac3EN0GqK40pC9gGi/YixvKyZ24qMP/9HiGW7w=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

---

### Overall solution

There is no need to use `useCallback` with `increment` in your case. Do one of the following:

```
// Add count effect dependency
const increment = () => setCount(count + 1)
useEffect(increment, [count, formVal]) 

// or use functional updater of `useState`
const increment = () => setCount(prev => prev + 1)
useEffect(increment, [formVal])
```

For the sake of completness, `useCallback` solution:

```
const increment = useCallback(() => setCount(count + 1), [count]) 
useEffect(increment, [increment, formVal])
```

`useEffect` calls are determined by its dependency array. And inline click callbacks for `button` and primitive DOM nodes [are cheap in terms of performance](https://cdb.reacttraining.com/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578). So you don't need `useCallback`.

If `increment` implementation is really simple, you can even inline it for all cases.

Comment: PS: Created a [bug report](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18716) for the missing dependency case of non-inline effect callbacks.

Comment: Awesome, so a little followup. @Shubham Khatri down below mentioned that 'In your case the reference of increment function will be different for button element on every render'. So doesn't this mean that using it in the way I have, without useCallback, is actually worse than passing it inline? Sort of confused on the consensus here, thanks again

Comment: Depends on what you understand by 'worse'. Both the inline and your version of `increment` without `useCallback` have the same closure scope and are re-created on render, so it doesn't matter so much. An argument for your version would be reusability of `increment` inside the comp. But the function is so simple, that indeed I would regard the inline variant as better style because of code co-location (you don't have to search for the function declarations somewhere else).

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between useEffect and useCallback.

useEffect calls the function callback when dependency array changes. useCallback recreates the function with newclosure when dependency array changes. Also useCallback returns a function useEffect does't

So even though you can pass increment to useEffect to actually execute the function its not equivalent to useCallback wherein the function is just re-created when dependency array changes. In your case the reference of increment function will be different for button element on every render

The best way to implement the above code would be

```js
// Get a hook function
const {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useCallback
} = React;

const Example = ({
  title
}) => {
  const [formVal, setFormVal] = useState("")
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const increment = useCallback(() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1), [])

  
  useEffect(increment, [formVal])

  return ( <
    div >
    <input onChange={(e) => setFormVal(e)} placeholder="test"/>
    <
    p > {
      title
    } < /p> <
    p > You interacted {
      count
    }
    times < /p> <
    button onClick = {
      increment
    } >
    Click me <
    /button> < /
    div >
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render( <
  Example title = "Example using Hooks:" / > ,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Also even though you pass in increment or a normal callback to useEffect, the function reference for useEffect usage is only changed when the dependency array changes